# Matlab call subplot with multiple volshow 3d images

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to plot two volumetric reconstructions created with MATLAB's [volshow](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/volshow.html) function.

I've tried calling subplot like I would with a plot but the second volshow object overwrites the first volshow object in the figure.

here's a code snippet that recreates the problem

```
vol1 = rand([10 10 10]);
vol2 = rand([10 10 10]);
subplot(1,2,1)
volshow(vol1);
subplot(1,2,2)
volshow(vol2);
```

How do I get both images to display simultaneously on the same figure?

Comment: If your two volumes have the same size, you can try to use `volshow([vol1,vol2])` or `volshow([vol1;vol2])` according to your need. I don't know if the volshow function support two "separated" volume.

Comment: @obchardon appreciate the feedback however, that will concatenate both 3d arrays into a single 3darray and when viewed it will not be separated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the image processing toolbox so I can't test this.

The online help for `volshow` that you link only lists `figure` and `uipanel` objects as possible parents.

So I would try:

```
f = figure;
p1 = uipanel(f,'Position',[0,0,0.5,1]);
p2 = uipanel(f,'Position',[0.5,0,0.5,1]);
volshow(vol1, 'Parent',p1);
volshow(vol2, 'Parent',p2);
```